# Move child array to parent array php

Tags: php

I have an php array like:-

```
Array
(
   [colors] => Array
      (
        [0] => white
        [1] => Yellow
        [2] => Black
        [3] => white
        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => white
                [1] => Black
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [0] => white
                [1] => Black
            )
        [6] => white
        [7] => red
    )

)
```

Now I want Output like:

```
Array
(
   [colors] => Array
    (
      [0] => white
      [1] => Yellow
      [2] => Black
      [3] => white
      [4] => white
      [5] => Black
      [6] => white
      [7] => Black
      [8] => white
      [9] => red
   )
)
```

Means if array element has array value then it will be moved to parent. I don't want child layer. Please suggest how can I achieve

Comment: AnkitaAgrawal  check the answers and mark+up-vote one as accepted answer which is correct for you. You can up-vote others too if they are useful.Thanks

Comment: people not responding

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_splice()` like so:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr['colors']); $i++) {
    if (is_array($arr['colors'][$i])) {
        array_splice($arr['colors'], $i, 1, $arr['colors'][$i]);
    }
}
```

Or might as well create a **function** for it to make a **one-liner call**:

```
function flattenArray($arr) {
    for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
        if (is_array($arr[$i])) {
            array_splice($arr, $i, 1, $arr[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $arr; // flattened array
}

$result = flattenArray($arr['colors']);
```

Comment: This should be approved answer Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
  foreach($myarray as $array){
        foreach($array as $val){
            $array_1[] = $val;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an way.

```
$someArray = ['YOUR_ARRAY_HERE']; 
$newArray = [];

foreach ($someArray as $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $innerValue) {
            array_push($newArray, $innerValue);
        }
        continue;
    }

    array_push($newArray, $value);

}

print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, best and optimal solution

```
$new_array['colors'] = array();
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
$list = iterator_to_array($it,false);
$new_array['colors'] = $list;

print_r($new_array);
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/665238)**